# How should I use While in a sentence?

Tags: grammar

If I use “while “in a sentence, I need to use verb ing only?
 For example : I saw a Pigeon While I was driving.

Answer (score 1):

**No you can use while without** the, "verb ing" as you put it.

**-ing** is used as a suffix to form the present participle of regular verbs. therefore in another tense you would not use the **-ing**

While can be used instead of **during the time that**, or **at the same time as**

While can also be used to replace **Although** and **But** in a sentence

> I read it while you were drying your hair
>
> I thought I heard him come in while we were having dinner.
>
> I'm acting as deputy while the boss is away.
>
> While I accept that he's not perfect in many respects, I do actually like the man.

[Use full link to C.E.D for reference](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/while)

Comment: Thank you very much